# How to solve polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots-of-cubics

Solve the equation $64x^3-240x^2+284x-105=0$ given that the roots are in an arithmetic 
.
I tried having the roots as $a, (a+d), (a+2d)$ 
Factorising out $a$, 
$a(1+d+2d)$

Comment: And what did you get using those roots?

Answer (score 3):

You could try $a-d, a,$ and $a+d$.

Then you would have $a(a^2-d^2)=\frac{105}{64}$, but more importantly you would have $3a=\frac{240}{64}$. Both by Vieta's formulas.

Comment: There is a possibility that $d$ is complex. Would it still count as an arithmetic progression

Comment: @Plato Why not?

Answer (score 2):

Using the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), the roots may involve the factors of the coefficients of the first and last terms. We can see that $64=4^3$ and $105=3\times5\times7$ and we can factor this polynomial easily.

$$64x^3-240x^2+284x-105=0=(4 x - 3) (4 x - 5) (4 x - 7)$$
so we have:

$$x=\frac{3}{4}, \frac{5}{4}, \frac{7}{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using the cubic formula. Since the discriminant is negative, you have $3$ real solutions, and should use the trig form, $$ax^{3}+bx^{2}+cx+d=0,\ x=\frac{2\sqrt{b^{2}-3ac}\cos\left(\frac{1}{3}\cos^{-1}\left(-\frac{b^{3}-4.5abc+13.5a^{2}d}{\sqrt{\left(b^{2}-3ac\right)^{3}}}\right)\right)-b}{3a}$$ or use the rational root theorem to get $1$ solution, then solve for the other $2$ in terms of the $1$st. $$x_{2,\ 3}=\frac{\sqrt{b^{2}-4ac-3a^{2}x_{1}^{2}-2abx_{1}}-b-ax_{1}}{2a}$$